# How to cehck data is exit or not in json formate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a static data json object. When I enter the corresponding roll key (101, for example) in the search box and press the button, the values appear.

If I enter the wrong roll key then the wrong roll key should show in an alert. Otherwise the corresponding values should appear.

correct roll no as like 101, 102, 103, 104 .
Show to data is fine but wrong roll no alert how to do it.

My code is

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 

    
    var rollno = {
    "101": [ {"name": "rohit", "rollNo": "1", "fname":"nro"}],
    "102": [ {"name": "azadrohit", "rollNo": "2" , "fname":"nrodf"}],
    "103": [ {"name": "rohitmalik", "rollNo": "3", "fname":"nrowexs"}],
    "104": [ {"name": "azdm", "rollNo": "4" , "fname":"nrosjyed"}]
    };
    
    
    $('#showD').on('click', function(){
     var rollnoINput = $('#searchDetails').val();
        var updateName = rollno[rollnoINput][0].name;
        var updateRollNo = rollno[rollnoINput][0].rollNo;
        var updateFname = rollno[rollnoINput][0].fname;
        
        
        $('#rollNo').html(updateRollNo);
     $('#cname').html(updateName);
     $('#fname').html(updateFname);
        
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="searchDetails" />

<button id="showD">Click  to result</button>

<div id="rollNo"></div>
<div id="cname"></div>
<div id="fname"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check whether the object has a key of rollNoINput. You can do this by checking that the [type](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/typeof.php) is not undefined. See below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {



var rollno = {
    "101": [{
        "name": "rohit",
        "rollNo": "1",
        "fname": "nro"
    }],
    "102": [{
        "name": "azadrohit",
        "rollNo": "2",
        "fname": "nrodf"
    }],
    "103": [{
        "name": "rohitmalik",
        "rollNo": "3",
        "fname": "nrowexs"
    }],
    "104": [{
        "name": "azdm",
        "rollNo": "4",
        "fname": "nrosjyed"
    }]
};


$('#showD').on('click', function() {
    var rollnoINput = $('#searchDetails').val();
    if (typeof(rollno[rollnoINput]) != 'undefined') {
        var updateName = rollno[rollnoINput][0].name;
        var updateRollNo = rollno[rollnoINput][0].rollNo;
        var updateFname = rollno[rollnoINput][0].fname;


        $('#rollNo').html(updateRollNo);
        $('#cname').html(updateName);
        $('#fname').html(updateFname);
    } else {
        alert(rollnoINput);
    }

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="searchDetails" />

<button id="showD">Click  to result</button>

<div id="rollNo"></div>
<div id="cname"></div>
<div id="fname"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check the existence of an object property:

```
$('#showD').on('click', function(){
    var rollnoINput = $('#searchDetails').val();

    if (rollno.hasOwnProperty(rollnoINput)) {
        var updateName = rollno[rollnoINput][0].name;
        var updateRollNo = rollno[rollnoINput][0].rollNo;
        var updateFname = rollno[rollnoINput][0].fname;

        $('#rollNo').html(updateRollNo);
        $('#cname').html(updateName);
        $('#fname').html(updateFname);

   } else {
     alert('Property not found');
   }

});
```